# What's the fastest way to copy a texture to another texture in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Here's the options I've found:

- glBlitFramebuffer: Create framebuffers for the textures, bind textures as GL_READ_FRAMEBUFER and GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, call glBlitFramebuffer().
- glCopyTexImage2D: My research so far says this method is probably slow.
- Shaders: Make a framebuffer and render target, render the source texture to the dest texture.

Comment: It's hard to tell which is faster. There are simply too many factors that come into play. You would have to test the 3 and figure it out for yourself. Also keeping in mind that it might vary according to platform/hardware, some might optimize a given path, some other...

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a version of OpenGL.

The fastest is likely to be [glCopyImageSubData](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glCopyImageSubData). However, that's only available in recent versions of desktop GL.